# Send Email (Emailmessage) to update Lead custom field

Tags: apex, emailmessage

The  lead object  has a field "Interaction count" . It is a number field. I am using this field for  an active process builder  which is working  on the below criteria:

If any Task is created , It will add+1 to the "Interaction Count "Field.
If I am creating Task by using" LoginActivity" , my interaction count is showing a increment which is good.

But If I am using "Email" , and sending an Email to the vendors, It is not considering as a Task and there is no increment in the " Interaction Count "Field.
I tried Process builder and Flow but **not worked out.** Can we do via "Apex coding" or create custom button and use Trigger?
Any help is appreciated...
Thanks

Comment: Do you have "enhanced email" enabled?

Comment: Yes ,"enhanced email" enabled.